# How to prove that there is no integer $n \gt 1$ such that $(\exp n)(\log n)$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory

Comments to [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/31870/20307) suggest the following assertion:

> There is no integer $n \gt 1$ such that $(\exp n)(\log\ n)$ is an integer.

Any ideas how this might be proved?